# How can I toggle one icon which triggers the disabling of another icon in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am developing an app with react and redux toolkit. I am using an API. the part that I would like help with is this:
I have a favorite Icon. this icon takes a copy of the movie and displays it in the favorite section. There is another icon which is for watched movies. so the idea is that if I click on watched it should disable only the favorite icon of the movie card I clicked. however, it disables all favorite icons for all movie cards. The watched icon is referred to as Eye the favorite icon is referred to as star

This is the eye component (Watched)

```
    import { useState } from "react";
    import { BsEyeSlash, BsEyeFill } from "react-icons/bs";
    import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
    import {
        add_watched,
        remove_watched,
        add_occupied,
        remove_occupied,
    } from "../features/animeSlice";
    
    const Eye = ({ anime, type }) => {
        const [active_eye, setActive_eye] = useState(false);
        const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
        const toggle_eye = () => {
            if (!active_eye) {
                setActive_eye((prev) => {
                    return !prev;
                });
                dispatch(add_watched(anime));
                dispatch(add_occupied(type));
            } else {
                setActive_eye((prev) => {
                    return !prev;
                });
                dispatch(remove_watched(anime?.mal_id));
                dispatch(remove_occupied());
            }
        };
    
        return (
            <div>
                {!active_eye ? (
                    <BsEyeSlash
                        className="text-xl text-green-500 icons_1"
                        onClick={toggle_eye}
                    />
                ) : (
                    <BsEyeFill
                        className={"text-xl text-red-500 icons_1"}
                        onClick={toggle_eye}
                    />
                )}
            </div>
        );
    };
    
    export default Eye;
```

This is the Star Component (Favorite)

```
    import { useState } from "react";
    import { AiOutlineStar, AiFillStar } from "react-icons/ai";
    import { add_favourite, remove_favourite } from "../features/animeSlice";
    import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
     
    const Star = ({ anime }) => {
        const { value} = useSelector((state) => state.anime);
        const [active_star, setActive_star] = useState(false);
        const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
        const toggle_star = () => {
            if (!active_star) {
                setActive_star((prev) => {
                    return !prev;
                });
                dispatch(add_favourite(anime));
                
            } else {
                setActive_star((prev) => {
                    return !prev;
                });
                dispatch(remove_favourite(anime?.mal_id));
            }
        };
    
        return (
            <div>
                {!active_star ? (
                    <AiOutlineStar
                        className={
                            value === "occupied"
                                ? "text-xl text-gray-300 pointer-events-none"
                                : "text-xl text-yellow-500 icon_1"
                        }
                        onClick={toggle_star}
                    />
                ) : (
                    <AiFillStar
                        className={
                            value === "occupied"
                                ? "text-xl text-gray-300 pointer-events-none"
                                : "text-xl text-yellow-500 icon_1"
                        }
                        onClick={toggle_star}
                    />
                )}
            </div>
        );
    };
    export default Star;
```

this is the redux toolkit slice

```
   

     import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
        
        const initialState = {
            favourite: [],
            watched: [],
            value: "",
            page:""
        };
        
        const animeSlice = createSlice({
            name: "anime",
            initialState,
            reducers: {
                add_favourite(state, { payload }) {
                    state.favourite.push(payload);
                },
                remove_favourite(state, { payload }) {
                    state.favourite = state.favourite.filter(
                        (anime) => anime?.mal_id !== payload
                    );
                },
                add_watched(state, { payload }) {
                    state.watched.push(payload);
                    
                    
                },
                remove_watched(state, { payload }) {
                    state.watched = state.watched.filter((anime) => anime?.mal_id !== payload);
                },
                add_occupied(state, { payload }) {
                    state.value = payload;
                },
                remove_occupied(state) {
                    state.value = "";
                },
                pageNumber(state, { payload }) {
                    state.page = payload
                }
            },
        });
        
        export const {
            add_favourite,
            remove_favourite,
            add_watched,
            remove_watched,
            add_occupied,
            remove_occupied,
            pageNumber
        } = animeSlice.actions;
        export default animeSlice.reducer;
    
    This is the component that holds the component of eye and star
```

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Eye from "./Eye";
import Star from "./Star";



const TopAnime = ({ anime }) => {
    //pagination
    
    //

    
    //
    let colorYear = (year) => {
        if (year === "N/A") {
            return "text-violet-500";
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    };

    return (
        <section className="grand px-4 pt-2 pb-5 w-64 bg-white/5 bg-opacity-80 backdrop-blur-sm rounded-lg cursor-pointer font-poppins animate-slideup">
            <div className="pb-1 wrapper_icons">
                <div className="wrapper_hover">
                    <Eye anime={anime} type="occupied" />
                    <Star anime={anime} />
                </div>
                
            </div>
            <Link to={`/anime/${anime?.mal_id}`}>
                <div className="wrapper_1 flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
                    <div className="h-[313px] w-[219px]">
                        <img
                            src={anime?.images?.jpg?.large_image_url}
                            alt={anime?.title}
                            className="h-full w-full"
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="flex flex-col mt-3">
                    <p className="text-sm text-white truncate mx-1">
                        {anime?.title_english ? anime?.title_english : anime?.title}
                    </p>
                    <div className="flex justify-between items-center text-sm text-yellow-500 mx-1">
                        <p className={colorYear(anime?.year ? anime?.year : "N/A")}>
                            {anime?.year ? anime?.year : "N/A"}
                        </p>
                        <p
                            className={
                                anime?.score <= 7
                                    ? "text-cyan-500"
                                    : anime?.score <= 5
                                    ? "text-red-600"
                                    : "text-green-500"
                            }
                        >
                            {anime?.score}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Link>
        
        </section>
                    
    );
};

export default TopAnime;
```

```
This is where TopAnime is rendered
```

```
    import { useGetAnimeQuery } from "../features/API";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import TopAnime from "../components/TopAnime";
import Spinner from "../components/Spinner";
import { NavLink, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Paginator from "../components/Paginator";
//import ReactPaginate from "react-paginate";
import Pagination from "@mui/material/Pagination";

const Home = () => {
    
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
    

    const {
        data: manga = [],
        isLoading,
        isFetching,
        error,
    } = useGetAnimeQuery(page);
    const { data, pagination } = manga;
    
    //destructuring objects
    //const { data, pagination } = manga;

    //const top_anime = data;
    const total = Math.ceil(pagination?.items?.total / 24)
    
    //const current_page = pagination?.current_page;
    //const per_page = pagination?.items?.per_page;

    //const { items: pages } = total;

/*  let fetchData = async (page = 1) => {

        let res = await fetch(
            `https://api.jikan.moe/v4/top/anime?page=${page}&limit=24`
        );
        let query = await res.json();
        const { data, pagination } = query;
        let totalPages = Math.ceil(pagination?.items.total / 24);
        setPageCount(totalPages);
        setData(data);
        
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        
        
        fetchData();
    }, []);

 */
```

```
        import { useGetAnimeQuery } from "../features/API";
    import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
    import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import TopAnime from "../components/TopAnime";
    import Spinner from "../components/Spinner";
    import { NavLink, Link } from "react-router-dom";
    import Paginator from "../components/Paginator";
    //import ReactPaginate from "react-paginate";
    import Pagination from "@mui/material/Pagination";
    
    const Home = () => {
        
        const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
        
    
        const {
            data: manga = [],
            isLoading,
            isFetching,
            error,
        } = useGetAnimeQuery(page);
        const { data, pagination } = manga;
        
        //destructuring objects
        //const { data, pagination } = manga;
    
        //const top_anime = data;
        const total = Math.ceil(pagination?.items?.total / 24)
        
        //const current_page = pagination?.current_page;
        //const per_page = pagination?.items?.per_page;
    
        //const { items: pages } = total;
    
    /*  let fetchData = async (page = 1) => {
    
            let res = await fetch(
                `https://api.jikan.moe/v4/top/anime?page=${page}&limit=24`
            );
            let query = await res.json();
            const { data, pagination } = query;
            let totalPages = Math.ceil(pagination?.items.total / 24);
            setPageCount(totalPages);
            setData(data);
            
        };
    
        useEffect(() => {
            
            
            fetchData();
        }, []);
    
     */
        
        const handleChange = (event, value) => {
            setPage(value);
        };
    
        const display = data?.map((anime) => (
            <TopAnime anime={anime} key={anime.mal_id} />
        ));
    
    
    
        //const pageCount = Math.ceil(pagination?.items?.total / 24);
    
         if (isLoading) {
            return <Spinner color_1={"#141e30"} color_2={"#243b55"} />;
        } else if (isFetching) {
            return <Spinner color_1={"#141e30"} color_2={"#243b55"} />;
        } else if (error) {
            console.log("ERROR =>", error.message);
        } 
    
        return (
            <section className="bg-gradient-to-r from-[#141e30] to-[#243b55]">
                <div className="container font-poppins">
                    <div className="grid grid-cols-4 gap-3 place-items-center px-20">
                        {/* {top_anime &&
                            top_anime?.map((anime) => (
                                <TopAnime anime={anime} key={anime.mal_id} />
                            ))} */}
                        {display}
                    </div>
                    <div className="button text-yellow-500 flex items-center justify-center mt-2 pb-2 cursor-pointer">
                        {/* <Paginator paginated={paginated} NumP={pagination?.last_visible_page} /> */}
                        {/* <ReactPaginate
                            previousLabel={"Previous"}
                            nextLabel={"Next"}
                            onPageChange={(page) => fetchData(page.selected + 1)}
                            pageCount={pageCount}
                            className="flex space-x-2"
                            activeClassName="active"
                        /> */}
                        <Pagination count={total} page={page} onChange={handleChange} defaultPage={1} boundaryCount={3} color="secondary" sx={{button:{color:'#ffffff'}}} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        );
    };
    export default Home;
```

Comment: Can you [edit] the post to include how this `TopAnime` component is rendered? I'm assuming you are rendering from an array?

Comment: I have included what you asked me to: Where TopAnime is rendered. Yes its rendered as an array (.map)

Comment: Am I correctly understanding that clicking the "eye" button toggles the "watched" state, and in doing so this is changing the favorites array in the Redux store? Would it be possible for you to create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: You understood correctly. here is the sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/anime-f4qrnb

Comment: Thanks, the sandbox is now running from what I can see.

Comment: What does the "occupied" state represent?

Comment: The occupied state is supposed to be a trigger when I click on the eye icon (which represents the watched anime) it should disable the star icon of the anime movie card only. however, if you click on an eye icon of a movie it will disable all the star icons of all the movies. which is not what I want.  if you want to see the occupied is being used. It is in the star component.

Comment: So basically "occupied" is supposed to be the Redux state that stores whether a movie has been watched or not?

Comment: no what stores the watched is the eye icon which has its separate dispatch. It's called add_watched. After The watched movie has been added another dispatch is triggered called add_occupied which takes the prop type. Type contain the string occupied. occupied greys out the star icon. the problem is that all star icons are greyed out. I only need one star to be greyed out. try it you will see it.

Comment: Well, I think that's what I'm driving at.... if a movie has been marked "watched", the "favorites" star should be disabled, yeah? You are saying you are just trying to use the "occupied" state as a "connection" between ***a*** movie being marked "watched" and disabling the star?

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The issue with the code/current implementation is that there is only ***one*** `state.anime.value` and ***one*** "occupied" value. Each time a movie's "watched" status is toggled the Redux state sets/unsets the single `state.anime.value` state. In other words, you can toggle N movies "watched" and the `state.anime.value` value is `"occupied"`, but then toggling just 1 movie back to "unwatched" and `state.anime.value` is reset back to `""`. All the `Star` components read this single state value and this is why the stars all toggle together.

## Solution

If you want ***a*** specific movie to toggle the `Star` component when the `Eye` icon is toggled then I think the solution is a bit simpler than you are making it out to be in your code.

The "eye" and "star" components effectively duplicate your Redux state and don't synchronize well with it. It's often considered a React anti-pattern to duplicate state. The `state.anime.favourite` and `state.anime.watched` arrays are all the app needs to know what has been marked "watched" and what has been favourited.

Update the `animeSlice` to store the `anime.mal_id` properties in objects instead of arrays to provide `O(1)` lookup in the UI. Remove the `anime.value` state as it's unnecessary.

animeSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  favourite: {},
  watched: {},
  page: ""
};

const animeSlice = createSlice({
  name: "anime",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    add_favourite(state, { payload }) {
      state.favourite[payload] = true;
    },
    remove_favourite(state, { payload }) {
      delete state.favourite[payload];
    },
    add_watched(state, { payload }) {
      state.watched[payload] = true;
      delete state.favourite[payload]; // un-star when adding as watched
    },
    remove_watched(state, { payload }) {
      delete state.watched[payload];
    },
    pageNumber(state, { payload }) {
      state.page = payload;
    }
  }
});

export const {
  add_favourite,
  remove_favourite,
  add_watched,
  remove_watched,
  pageNumber
} = animeSlice.actions;

export default animeSlice.reducer;
```

Update the `Eye` and `Star` components to read the ***true*** state from the store. These components should pass `anime.mal_id` to the dispatched actions and use `anime.mal_id` to check the watched/favourites map objects.

Eye

```
import { BsEyeSlash, BsEyeFill } from "react-icons/bs";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { add_watched, remove_watched } from "../features/animeSlice";

const Eye = ({ anime }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { watched } = useSelector((state) => state.anime);

  const isWatched = watched[anime.mal_id];

  const toggle_eye = () => {
    dispatch((isWatched ? remove_watched : add_watched)(anime.mal_id));
  };

  const Eye = isWatched ? BsEyeFill : BsEyeSlash;
  const className = [
    "text-xl icons_1",
    isWatched ? "text-green-500" : "text-red-500"
  ].join(" ");

  return (
    <div>
      <Eye className={className} onClick={toggle_eye} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Eye;
```

Star

```
import { AiOutlineStar, AiFillStar } from "react-icons/ai";
import { add_favourite, remove_favourite } from "../features/animeSlice";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

const Star = ({ anime }) => {
  const { favourite, watched } = useSelector((state) => state.anime);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const isFavorited = favourite[anime.mal_id];
  const isWatched = watched[anime.mal_id];

  const toggle_star = () => {
    dispatch((isFavorited ? remove_favourite : add_favourite)(anime.mal_id));
  };

  const Star = isFavorited ? AiFillStar : AiOutlineStar;
  const className = [
    "text-xl",
    isWatched ? "text-gray-300 pointer-events-none" : "text-yellow-500 icon_1"
  ].join(" ");

  return (
    <div>
      <Star className={className} onClick={toggle_star} />
    </div>
  );
};
export default Star;
```

[image: Edit how-can-i-toggle-one-icon-which-triggers-the-disabling-of-another-icon-in-react]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. it worked. But there is an issue. in Redux the whole information is not included in watched object. only the id is there along with the word true. another thing if I favourite something I still get id with the word true and then if hit also watched the favourite redux still has the id with the word true. it is not removed. The reason why I need the information is because I am goind to transfer it to a page called watched. here is the image link : https://ibb.co/Ry421SQ

Comment: @HaroonIslam So are you saying that when the "watched"/"Eye" icon is toggled that you want to  disable the star **and also *un-star*** the movie too?

Comment: @HaroonIslam The basic reason only the movie id is stored in these parts of state is to not duplicate any of the state, i.e. we try to keep state as minimal as is necessary, e.g. "state" is the minimal representation of your UI. A watched or favorited movie list is easily derived by filtering the array of movies by what id values are in `state.watched` or `state. favourite`. Does this part make sense?

Comment: So are you saying that when the "watched"/"Eye" icon is toggled that you want to disable the star and also un-star the movie too? (Yes that's exactly what I am looking for). the second comment I did not really understand sorry. Because there is no complete information in watched why I click the Eye. info like id, movie title, year, etc. with the word true and just the id I don't know how to get the information and transfer it to the watched page.

Comment: @HaroonIslam You would delete the id from the `state.favourite` when adding the id to `state.watched`. I've updated answer and sandbox. As for the deriving of a "watched" list it's something like `const { data: manga = {} } = useGetAnimeQuery(page);`, `const { data = [], pagination } = manga;`, `const { watched } = useSelector((state) => state.anime);`, and then `const watchedList = data.filter(anime => watched[anime.mal_id]);`.

Comment: I am sorry could you please do the last part in sandbox. how to get the watched id and its information into the watched page (I have created the watched page). I am a little bit confused about it. because if I try to do the way you mentioned above its goind to be two different information one in TopAnime and Another in Watched.

Comment: @HaroonIslam Which one is the "watched" page? Or do you just want/need me to create a route, i.e. `"/watched"` that renders a component that computes the "watched" list from the Redux store?

Comment: I have added the "Watched" Route and "Watched" Page. Can you please show me how I can get the info and display it on the page.

Comment: @HaroonIslam Sorry, where have you added this code that I could take a look at?

Comment: I am sorry. It did not save. I have saved it now. I hope you find it. Its not code but I have created the Watched page and added the Route in App.js. if it did not save can you create the route and watched page and show me how to render the watched movie on the watched page.

Comment: @HaroonIslam Are you editing the sandbox you linked in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74977223/how-can-i-toggle-one-icon-which-triggers-the-disabling-of-another-icon-in-react#comment132327467_74977223)?

Comment: I am not sure how to save on sandbox. I press save but sometimes it does not save.

Comment: Yes. I have edited the sandbox you are mentioning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250920/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-haroon-islam).

Comment: Hello. Don't mean to bother you but can you help me with the issue we discussed yesterday? You remember that if I go to page 2 or page 3 etc... and clicked watched. It does not work.

Comment: @HaroonIslam Yup, I responded back to you in the chat a bit ago. Marking movies watched appears to be working in the sandbox I linked.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am sorry I know I have asked of you a lot and I am sure you are busy. You've really helped me and I have learned a lot from you. I was just wondering how can I allow the things that I do to persist. I mean if I click favourite or watched it stays that way even if I refresh the page also if I click watched and it goes to watched page I should remain that even if the page is refreshed. it will only be removed it I click the watched page again in the watched page.

Comment: @HaroonIslam If you have a need to persist the redux state then I'd suggest checking out [redux-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist). It's a pretty straightforward integration.

Comment: I have tried it but its not persisting. I am not sure if I am doing it wrong or something.

Comment: @HaroonIslam Responding back in chat.

Comment: Thank you for the persistance. its working. However, if I use pagination, click watched icon on a couple of movies,go to watched page then when I "go back", the page rerenders to the first page not to the page I was on when I clicked watched icons.

Comment: @HaroonIslam I see. So is the current page something you want to store in "app state", i.e. the store, instead of local component state of `Home`?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you just said. I think you choose the one that is most effective and easiest to do (so that I can understand it) regards.

Comment: @HaroonIslam That was a hint that if you want the "home" page to "remember" what the current page was that the `page` state should be moved into the Redux store so it (a) lives at the app level so it's not reset when navigating to `"/"` and (b) gets persisted with the store so reloading the page keeps the current active page.

Comment: Yes, that's what I would like. When you do it can you please, leave some comments so that I can understand when I study it.

Comment: @HaroonIslam https://codesandbox.io/s/how-can-i-toggle-one-icon-which-triggers-the-disabling-of-another-icon-in-react-forked-zz4uee?file=/src/pages/Home.jsx